# Multiple resources does not work in ipad - Kendo Scheduler

Tags: ipad, kendo-ui, scheduler, kendo-scheduler

I wrote below code to create an appointment for multiple attendees for web and worked perfectly. But for iPad it fails to submit selected attendees id to the model. I don't understand what's wrong here?

```
enter code here @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<AppointmentSummaryModel>()
.Name("scheduler")
.Mobile(MobileMode.Auto)
.Date(DateTime.Today)
.Timezone("Etc/UTC")
.Height(700)
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Read(read => read.Action("Schedules_Read", "Scheduler"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("Schedules_Create", "Scheduler"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Schedules_Update", "Scheduler"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Schedules_Destroy", "Scheduler"))
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id("Id");
        m.Field(f => f.OwnerID);
    })
)
.Views(views =>
{
    views.WeekView(s => s.Selected(true));
})
.Resources(resource =>
{
    resource.Add(m => m.OwnerID)
        .Title("Owner")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataColorField("Color")
        .Multiple(true)
        .BindTo(new[] {
            new { Text = "Alex", Value = 1, Color = "#f8a398" } ,
            new { Text = "Bob", Value = 2, Color = "#51a0ed" } ,
            new { Text = "Charlie", Value = 3, Color = "#56ca85" }
        });
})
)
```

Few screenshots of result

[Console errors when I select attendees name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d6sZ.png)

[image: image 1]

[Other than attendees everything is available in e.event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgHLu.png)

[image: image 2]

**Output needs to save the attendee name in the appointment which is not happening right now**

Comment: Please provide or at least explain what your output should be like.

Comment: Output needs to save the attendee name in the appointment which is not happening right now

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Any suggestions?

Comment: No, I don't know this language. Add above commented info to your question.